# Nosuchelement exception when activity is visible

Tags: appium, appium-android

Having this strange situation. My code is resulting in no such element exception in scenario 1, but in scenario 2 it’s working.

Note: This issue is only on Android, on iOS tests not having issue on login.

**Scenario 1: [FAIL]**

The activity loads,
Using webdriver wait for checking if the element is clickable,
Timeout after the time limit 20 - 30 second.
Debugging:
I am waiting for app to complete login on the emulator and then performed step 2. Still facing no such element exception despite of activity completely being loaded.

**Scenario 2: [PASS] pusing to background**
The activity loads,
Pushing app to background and bringing it back,
Using webdriver wait for checking if the element is clickable,
Element is recognized, going ahead with remaining tests.
Operating sytem:
Android - Nexus 6 emulator on Android 8.0

**POM:**

```
<testng.version>6.14.3</testng.version>
<appium.java.version>6.1.0</appium.java.version>
<apachepoi.version>3.17</apachepoi.version>
<selenium.version>3.14.0</selenium.version>
<allure.version>1.4.0.RC4</allure.version>
<aspectj.version>1.8.11</aspectj.version>
<firefox.version>3.14.0</firefox.version>
<sauceondemand.version>2.14</sauceondemand.version>
<sauceclientfactory.version>2.14</sauceclientfactory.version>
<saucetestng.version>2.1.23</saucetestng.version>
<log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
```

Comment: please add more details for more specific solution. As of now I can just say that use some synchronisation mechanism before interacting with elements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Abhishek_Mishra, I added updated the comment. I am using webdriver wait for waiting for an element till it's clickable.